# Modify column values with list values when a condition is satisfied - PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to assign values to the dataframe column from a list on a condition, but my code only works on hard-coded replacements and not a dynamic version like lists.

And I can't convert the list directly to dataframe column bcuz its length is way shorter than the column's length

```
no_connections = network_data.map(lambda row: (row[1], 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b).collect()

network_data1 = network_data1\
                .withColumn("NoUserConnections", when(network_data1.NoUserConnections == 0, no_connections[0])
                .otherwise(network_data1.NoUserConnections))
```

I can also get the values of no_connections from a dataframe like so

```
network_data1.groupby('User').count().show()
```

My Dataframe looks like this:

```
+---+----+-----------+-----------------+
|_c0|User|Connections|NoUserConnections|
+---+----+-----------+-----------------+
|  0|   0|          1|                0|                       
|  1|   0|          2|                0|                       
|  2|   0|          3|                0|                       
|  3|   0|          4|                0|                       
|  4|   0|          5|                0|                       
|  5|   0|          6|                0|                       
|  6|   1|          7|                1|                       
|  7|   1|          8|                1|                       
|  8|   1|          9|                1|                       
|  9|   1|         10|                1|                      
+---+----+-----------+-----------------+
```

and I want to put the number of instances of each User value to their corresponding User like this

```
+---+----+-----------+-----------------+
|_c0|User|Connections|NoUserConnections|
+---+----+-----------+-----------------+
|  0|   0|          1|                6|                       
|  1|   0|          2|                6|                       
|  2|   0|          3|                6|                       
|  3|   0|          4|                6|                       
|  4|   0|          5|                6|                       
|  5|   0|          6|                6|                       
|  6|   1|          7|                4|                       
|  7|   1|          8|                4|                       
|  8|   1|          9|                4|                       
|  9|   1|         10|                4|                      
+---+----+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Include an example to help us understand what you are trying to do. Follow [Minimally Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples/48427186#48427186) to better structure your question.

Comment: Are you trying to find for each user the number of times they appear in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to compute the number of occurences of each user in the dataframe and assign it to the user. You can use `window` functions in PySpark and apply a `count` aggregate.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

data = [(0, 0, 1, 0, ),
        (1, 0, 2, 0, ),
        (2, 0, 3, 0, ),
        (3, 0, 4, 0, ),
        (4, 0, 5, 0, ),
        (5, 0, 6, 0, ),
        (6, 1, 7, 1, ),
        (7, 1, 8, 1, ),
        (8, 1, 9, 1, ),
        (9, 1, 10, 1, ),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Id", "User", "Connections", "NoUserConnections", ))

window_spec = W.partitionBy("User").rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.unboundedFollowing)

df.withColumn("NoUserConnections", F.count("Connections").over(window_spec)).show()
```

### Output

```
+---+----+-----------+-----------------+
| Id|User|Connections|NoUserConnections|
+---+----+-----------+-----------------+
|  0|   0|          1|                6|
|  1|   0|          2|                6|
|  2|   0|          3|                6|
|  3|   0|          4|                6|
|  4|   0|          5|                6|
|  5|   0|          6|                6|
|  6|   1|          7|                4|
|  7|   1|          8|                4|
|  8|   1|          9|                4|
|  9|   1|         10|                4|
+---+----+-----------+-----------------+
```